# Migration from Glassfish to Payara

Tags: server, glassfish, payara

I've my complete service running currently with glassfish. But due to many of the glassfish bugs, I want to migrate my system to Payara.
I want to know what could be the best way to do this and what things I should keep in, so that it doesn;t affect the running service?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using GlassFish 4, you can just upgrade the server to Payara Server, which is entirely compatible. If you have issues, please raise them in the Payara project github.

You can upgrade from GlassFish 4 to any version of Payara Server as if you would upgrade from an older version of Payara Server. You can follow the [Payara Server documentation about upgrading](https://payara.gitbooks.io/payara-server/content/documentation/user-guides/upgrade-payara.html) or follow [this blog post](http://blog.payara.fish/how-to-upgrade-payara-server) describing the same thing.

In short, you basically need to move the `domains` directory (and `nodes` directory if you use nodes) from your GlassFish installation to a new Payara Server installation and everything should just work when you start the new installation of Payara Server as you would start GlassFish.

If you have an older version of GlassFish (e.g. 3 or 2), you may try upgrading directly to Payara Server with the same approach, but expect some issues. You should follow advice on the internet about how to upgrade from older GlassFish to GlassFish 4 and apply the same advice with Payara Server.

Comment: after upgrading to payara 171 server i m getting one issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44917544/application-is-not-loading-after-upgrading-to-payara-4-1-1-171, if you have any idea plz let me know