# Application is not loading after upgrading to payara 4.1.1.171

Tags: glassfish, compression, http-compression, payara

Upgraded server from `glassfish 3.1` to `payara 4.1.1.171`, took the `glassfish` config backup and restored to `payara 4.1.1.171`. After that my application is not loading and in console it throws this error **net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING**

If i change the compression attribute to 'off' then application is loading .

```
<http request-timeout-seconds="2700" chunking-enabled="false" compressable-mime-type="text/html,text/xml,text/plain,image/gif,image/jpeg,image/png,text/css,text/javascript,application/json,application/xml" max-connections="250" compression="on" default-virtual-server="server">
```

In the above configuration if i change the compression="on" to compression="off" then its working fine. 
Don't why this is breaking in payara which was working in glassfish with same setting. I can't turn off the compression which will saves the bandwidth.

Note: Already some issues are reported similar to this [Chrome net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29894154/chrome-neterr-incomplete-chunked-encoding-error)
but this is not case for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue should be fixed in Payara 4.1.2.172 according to [this issue](https://github.com/payara/Payara/pull/1425)
Use that version instead of 4.1.1.171

Comment: Thanks OndrejM for your response..Even i tried with Payara Server 4.1.2.172 & payara server 4.1.2.173-SNAPSHOT but no luck the same issue is coming..

Comment: Then it's probably a bug or misconfiguration after the upgrade. You should raise an issue [on Github](https://github.com/payara/Payara/issues).

Comment: Thanks OndrejM i already raise an issue in github https://github.com/payara/Payara/issues/1739 ,they says it got fixed in payara 171 but not fixed in even 172,173-snapshot